# What exactly does SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE mean?

Tags: windows, winapi

I was unable to find any hint of the exact meaning of the SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE ShellExecute return value.

I know that MSDN says "The file name association is incomplete or invalid", but what exactly does that mean? In what situations can it occur?

Comment: It probably means there's something broken in your Registry, in the part that associates the extension of the file you're ShellExecuting with the program used to open it.

Comment: @Medinoc Have you actually run into it or you're just making a guess based on the MSDN description?

Comment: @gbr: I'm making a guess based on the constant name and medium knowledge of Windows and file associations.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Proper error handling is what I meant to do, and that should include returning an helpful message to the user or at least have an idea of the meaning of the error so that to help the user. The aim is not just to not crash the program but also to manage to open the file in some way.

Comment: In that case the answer is clear. Stop calling `ShellExecute`.

Comment: @Medinoc That's what I guessed as well, but I wanted to find some certain information, and at least know if it's an error that can still occur or it's just a relic from ancient Windows versions

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What does that mean? If you mean that there's a better way of programmatically open a file, ok, please tell me about that, but in any case I was specifically looking for the meaning of this specific return of this specific function so you're comments seem off-topic.

Comment: I've done exactly that in my answer. Have you read that yet? Perhaps you need to refresh this page. If you want to get information about a failure you are expected to call `ShellExecuteEx` because that function is capable of returning meaningful error codes. And `ShellExecute` cannot return meaningful error codes.

Comment: Medinoc's comment is the correct answer.  It can find an association in the registry but the shell keys that say which program to execute are missing or invalid.  "Your registry is corrupted" is not the kind of message you should ever display to a user, the heart attack that causes is *way* too much of a liability.  You can't be sure you are correct when you can't rely on basic assumptions anymore.  Only display what you know, shouldn't be more than "ShellExecute failed with error %d".

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I had not yet seen the answer, I think you deleted your earlier comment while I was replying. Anyway thank you, your answer actually solved my issue.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, so you know this by personal experience, or you remember some old document?
I made some experiments now but even on a not-so-recent Windows XP I couldn't get a SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE back. Do you have any idea which was the last Windows version that still returned it?
Given the mentions to 16-bit in the documentation I guess it might have already been obsolete in Windows 95.

I ask that just out of curiosity, for the sake of software archeology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best information on this can be found in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762153.aspx). Which supplies the text:

> The file name association is incomplete or invalid.

Which is what you've found out. To be honest it seems reasonably clear what it means, specifically that there is something wrong with the file association that has prevented the function from completing.

As to what `SE_ERR_ASSOCINCOMPLETE` means in full gory detail, that is an exhaustive list of all possible failure modes, you'll likely never find out. This is a deprecated function that exists solely to maintain backwards compatibility. The chances of Microsoft offering more insight into its works are vanishingly small.

The smart play here is not to call `ShellExecute`. Its error handling is crippled. Instead use [`ShellExecuteEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb762154.aspx). When that fails, use `GetLastError` to get a Win32 error code.

Read more about that in Raymond Chen's article, [Why does ShellExecute return SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED for nearly everything?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/10/18/10360604.aspx) And then ask yourself what is the point of trying to gain a full understanding of the error codes that this function returns when most of the time you'll get `SE_ERR_ACCESSDENIED`.

Comment: Ok, this is a much more useful answer, thank you.
Indeed I noticed that there was no equivalent value among those listed as possible returns from GetLastError in ShellExecuteEx, and I suspected that might mean it was an obsolete value.

I accept your answer for the time being.
It would still be nice if someone knew more about it, just for historical curiosity, and if someone comes up I might accept his answer, but as far as I'm concerned my problem is solved.
Thank you again.